# Populate <select> dynamically from a database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to populate a select list with AJAX as follows:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Select State</td>
    <td>
    <select name="tractDrop" onchange="populateSelect(this.value)">
       <option value = "TX">TX</option>
       <option value = "LA">LA</option>
       <option value = "CA">CA</option>
    </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
        Select County
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="selectCounty">
        </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function populateSelect(str)
{
    if (str=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("selectCounty").innerHTML="";
            return;
         }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("selectCounty").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","selectajax.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET["q"];
    include '../include/engine.php';
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tractIndex WHERE tractState = '".$q."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo ("<option value=''> Select County </option>");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo ("<option value = $row[tractCounty]>$row[tractCounty]</option>");
    }
?>
```

Database table `tractIndex` has columns: `ID`, `tractState`, `tractCounty`

Everything works except the part in the javascript where I'm trying to populate the select options:

```
document.getElementById("selectCounty").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Thank you for anyone who is willing to help. Sorry for being so stupid!

Comment: Try to use jquery..it will reduces  ur code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code you posted is correct, the mistake is obvious,

```
document.getElementById("selectCounty").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
//The line above will try to find an element with the id 'selectCountry'
```

As far as I can see, none of your elements have such an id. Try this change

```
<select id="selectCounty"></select>
//Note the change from "name" to "id"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not given id to the drop down. You should give id first.
secondly I don't think by writing

```
document.getElementById("selectCounty").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

you can add option element to the select box. you need to come up with other solution.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
 echo "<select name='country'>";
    echo "<option value=''> Select County </option>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo ("<option value = $row[tractCounty]>$row[tractCounty]</option>");
        }

    echo "</select>";
```

HTML:
Replace

```
        <select name="selectCounty">
        </select>
```

with

```
<div id="city">
 </div>
```

Hope that will helps